# How to compute the monomial matrices?

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-topology, commutative-algebra, homology-cohomology

In GTM227 *Combinatorial Commutative Algebra*, Miller defined the monomial matrix to represent a map between two $\mathbb{N}^n$-graded free $S$ modules. Its columns are labeled by sourse degrees $a_p$ and its rows are labeled by target degrees $a_q$. The entry $\lambda_{qp}$ indicates that the basis vector of $S(-a_p)$ should map to an element with coefficient $\lambda_{qp}$ on the monomials, that is $x^{a_p-a_q}$ times the basis vector of $S(-a_q)$.
I wonder how to compute this entries $\lambda_{qp}$ explicitly, especially on the two examples given in the book: Example 1.25 for a Stanley-Reisner ring and Example 1.27 for the Koszul complex.